# Formula for permuted block sequences

Tags: permutations

In [permuted block randomization](http://www.wombatcollaboration.net/doc/protocol%20workshop/RCT%20Methods.pdf), a block size of $4$ has $6$ possible permutations:

> $AABB, ABAB, ABBA, BBAA, BABA, and BAAB$

And a block size of 6 has 8 possible permutations:

$AAABBB, BBBAAA, AABBAB, BBAABA, ABABAB, BABABA, ABAABB,$ and $BABBAA$

What formula is used to generate these permutations? Each block must contain an equal number of $As$ and $Bs$. Why isn't $ABBAAB$ a possible permutation when using a block size of $6$?

Comment: [These slides](https://medschool.vanderbilt.edu/cqs/files/cqs/2008Jun2008Fei.pdf) (see p.16) and [this paper](http://rheumatology.oxfordjournals.org/content/38/4/346.full.pdf) (p.347, the end of the first paragraph of the "**Methods**" section) say that all ${6\choose3}=20$ permutations can be used, but a number of documents on the internet do say that there are only eight possible permuations for a block size of $6$. So I guess the reason is not purely mathematical but something related to the context of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

They don't explain it.  For a block size of $6$ with $3\ A$'s, there are ${6 \choose 3}=20$ possibilities.  It sounds like they thought this was "random enough".